# How to do a like search against a multi-select parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report that returns data based on incoming parameters. I have a couple multi-select parameters and I'm handling those fine. My question is, I have a multi-select parameter where the user can type in portions of addresses, or multiple addresses. For example, they can type in `1234` and on the next line `5678` to search for addresses that have either one of these combinations.

This is the code:

```
AND (UPPER(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1) LIKE '%" & UCase(JOIN(Parameters!AccountAddress.Value, "%' OR UPPER(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1) LIKE '%")) & "%'))) "
```

And it does the right thing. Given the example of the user entering `1234` and on the next line `5678`, this code translates that to:

```
MEMBER_ADDRESS_1 LIKE '%1234%' OR MEMBER_ADDRESS_1 LIKE '%5678%'
```

Works great.

The issue is when the user hits Enter and goes to the next line, and *then* clicks Submit.

Now you have a blank as the last entry and the SQL gets translated as:

```
MEMBER_ADDRESS_1 LIKE '%1234%' OR MEMBER_ADDRESS_1 LIKE '%5678%' OR
MEMBER_ADDRESS_1 LIKE '%%'
```

And, of course, every address matches the query.

So the **Question:**
How can I prevent that last [CRLF] from adding a wildcard search for everything?

Comment: can you please update with your full code

Comment: you need to delete the CRLF from the param value before Join, Replace(Replace(Fields!ADDRESS.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), " ") try this code before join.

Comment: This is the complete line that I am trying to manipulate; **"AND (0 = " & Parameters!AccountAddress.Count & " OR (LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1))) > 0 AND (UPPER(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1) LIKE '%" & UCase(JOIN(Parameters!AccountAddress.Value, "%' OR UPPER(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1) LIKE '%")) & "%'))) "&**

Comment: Unfortunately, adding anything in the Join causes errors, even just an LTrim, and definitely a replace: **"AND (0 = " & Parameters!AccountAddress.Count & " OR (LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1))) > 0 AND (UPPER(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1) LIKE '%" & UCase(JOIN(LTRIM(Parameters!AccountAddress.Value), "%' OR UPPER(MEMBER_ADDRESS_1) LIKE '%")) & "%'))) "&**